# How can you include inherited properties in type definitions generated from .js files by tsc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, jsdoc

I am trying to add typescript support to a **vanilla javascript** library via .d.ts files. I am trying to generate these type definition files with the "tsc" command, but I am running into many "property 'propertyName' does not exist on type 'typeName'" errors.

This is happening on lines that attempt to call a function on an instance of a child class when that function is defined only in the code for its parent class. It seems that while JSDoc is capable of inferring inherited functions by using "@extends" in the JSDoc comments of a child class, tsc is not.

For example:

**ParentClass.js**

```
/**
* This is the parent class.
* 
* @class
*/
export class ParentClass {
  parentFunction(){
    console.log("Running parent function");
  }
}
```

**childClass.js**

```
/**
* This is a child class.
* 
* @class
* @extends {ParentClass}
*/

import {ParentClass} from "./ParentClass";

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  // ChildClass vars and functions here
}
```

**program.ts**

```
import {ChildClass} from "./ChildClass";

let cc = new ChildClass();
cc.parentFunction();
```

Upon attempting to compile the code, tsc will throw this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'parentFunction' does not exist on type
> 'ChildClass'.

Is there any way to resolve this issue? If there is no way to make the typescript compiler recognize inherited properties, is there some way to make tsc ignore this issue so it can at least finish generating the type definition files and allow me to manually add the missing properties to the corresponding child class type definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to import the other files on the `childClass.js` and `program.js`. It should be something like this:

---

**ParentClass.js**

```js
/**
* This is the parent class.
*
* @class
*/
export class ParentClass {
  parentFunction(){
    console.log("Running parent function");
  }
}
```

---

**childClass.js**

```js
import { ParentClass } from './ParentClass'

/**
* This is a child class.
*
* @class
* @extends {ParentClass}
*/
export class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  // ChildClass vars and functions here
}
```

---

**program.js**

```js
import { ChildClass } from './childClass'

let cc = new ChildClass();
cc.parentFunction();
```

Comment: D'oh! Thanks for pointing out this silly, silly mistake. However this is only a mistake I made while trying to write example code to illustrate the problem here on stackoverflow; the error is not present in the actual code that I am trying to generate type definitions for and is therefore not the cause of the issue.

Comment: With your updated question I was able to figure it out. I've edited my answer with the solution.

Comment: Heh heh. Again this is a problem with my example not present in the original code. Let me preempt any other "fixes" arising from my oversight by saying I'm working on top of someone else's JS library, and that library compiles and works perfectly on its own before any of my TS updates. In other words, any errors you find in my examples that would break vanilla JS irrespective of any typescript involvement have to be errors in my example that aren't present in the actual library that I'm adding TS support to.

Comment: Looks like there is some info still missing on your question. The code I've posted works just fine. Please clarify it a bit more so I can help you.

Also, a better way to add types to an already existing (3rd-party) JS library is to add a [Typescript declaration file (*.d.ts)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html)